# How to compare stdin with a file in Windows batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, filecompare

I want to write a auto code judge on Windows. 
Now I need to compare the output of test program with correct output. I know I need to use "fc", but I don't know how to write a command like that in Unix:

```
./hello.out < 1.in | diff - 1.out
```

in Windows:

```
hello.exe < 1.in | fc ??? 1.out (How to write?)
```

Comment: Just use an auxiliary file: `hello.exe < 1.in > hello.out  &  fc hello.out 1.out`. There is not a direct way.

Comment: well, the bat in Windows is so weak!!! I change to write powershell script~ Anyway, thank you!